# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive

I'm trying to load data into hive table while loading data into hive table i'm getting error "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0".
I don't know where I'm doing wrong, this error eting so much time of mine 
Any help will be appreciated

File:

```
test.txt
H,DatatypeCode,Description
K,03099,Metric Expanded mple Size
K,05307,Elapsed Day Factor
object testObject {

  //Check command line arguments(Input file) is exist or not

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

 val sourceTableName= "sourceHiveTable"
 val tmpTable="tmpHiveTable"
 val userNam =xxxx
 val passwrd =xxxx


 val readDF = sparkSession.read
       .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
       .option("delimiter", ",")
       .option("header", "true")
       .schema(customSchema)
       .load("test.txt")

def loadDFToDB(dataFrame:DataFrame,sourceTableName:String,tmpTable:String,driverName:String,userNam: String,passwrd:String) {
try{
    dataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView(tmpTable)
    console.log(INFO, Map(
      Message->"Storing dataframe into Temporary Table"
    ))
  } catch {

    case e: Exception => console.captureStackTrace(e , Map(
      Message -> "While converting dataframe to table process got failed,please check the stackTrace for more details"))
      fileProcessing.moveFile(sourceFileName,dirPath)
      sys.exit(1)
  }

  val connectionProperties = new Properties()
  connectionProperties.put("user", userNam)
  connectionProperties.put("password", passwrd)

  sparkSession.sqlContext.sql("select * from " + tmpTable )
  .write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append) // <--- Append in existing table
  .option("driver", "com.cloudera.hive.jdbc41.HS2Driver")
  .option("header","false")
  .jdbc(url, sourceTableName, connectionProperties)

  }

  loadDFToDB(readDF,sourceTableName,tmpTable,userNam,passwrd)

  }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at com.cloudera.hiveserver2.hivecommon.core.CoreUtils.parseSubName(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc41.HS2Driver.parseSubName(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hiveserver2.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hiveserver2.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:426)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that something is wrong with Hive url.
Since this line in stacktrace:

```
at com.cloudera.hiveserver2.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
```